# Use derived class in base class while derived class is declared after the base class

Tags: c++, derived-class

I have the header file

```
#ifndef CATEGORY_H
#define CATEGORY_H

#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Category
{
    private:
        std::string nameCategory;
        std::vector<Rule> setOfRules;
    protected:
    public:
        Category();
        Category(std::string nameCategory);
        void setIndexBankAccountEntry(unsigned int iBankAccountEntry);
};

class Rule : public Category
{
    private:
        std::function<void(int)> rule;
    protected:
    public:
        Rule();
        Rule(std::function<void(int)> rule);
};
#endif
```

in which the command `std::vector<Rule> setOfRules;` gives the error that `Rule` was not yet declared.

Switching the order of the declarations of the two classes gives

```
#ifndef CATEGORY_H
#define CATEGORY_H

#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Rule : public Category
{
    private:
        std::function<void(int)> rule;
    protected:
    public:
        Rule();
        Rule(std::function<void(int)> rule);
};

class Category
{
    private:
        std::string nameCategory;
        std::vector<Rule> setOfRules;
    protected:
    public:
        Category();
        Category(std::string nameCategory);
        void setIndexBankAccountEntry(unsigned int iBankAccountEntry);
};
#endif
```

but then I get the error that `expected class-name before ‘{’ token` for the line `class Rule : public Category`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Why does `Rule` have to inherit from `Category`?  Its seams that `Category`s contain `Rule`s which doesn't mean `Rule` needs to be a derived class.

Comment: See the answers below. What forward declaration says is "There will be a class called this but, for now, don't worry about what it is." This allows you to declare pointers to it but that's about all - you can't reference anything within the class until it has been properly declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a forward declaration for class `Rule` ( based on the first example ).

```
class Rule;
class Category
{
    private:
        std::string nameCategory;
        std::vector<Rule> setOfRules;
    protected:
    public:
        Category();
        Category(std::string nameCategory);
        void setIndexBankAccountEntry(unsigned int iBankAccountEntry);
};
// class Rule definition here
```

Check [here](http://ideone.com/msE5JS)

Answer (score 0):

You can forward declare class Rule:

```
#ifndef CATEGORY_H
#define CATEGORY_H

#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Rule; // <-- here

class Category
{
    private:
        std::string nameCategory;
        std::vector<Rule> setOfRules;
    protected:
    public:
        Category();
        Category(std::string nameCategory);
        void setIndexBankAccountEntry(unsigned int iBankAccountEntry);
};

class Rule : public Category
{
    private:
        std::function<void(int)> rule;
    protected:
    public:
        Rule();
        Rule(std::function<void(int)> rule);
};
#endif
```